# IntelliJ Angular 2 HTML support for * syntax

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 2017.1 doesn't seem to support the * syntax for HTML files with Angular 2. It seems that the autocompletion only suggest the template syntax (without the star).

[image: Angular suggestion]

[image: Autocompletion result]

Furthermore, the star syntax is marked as invalid with the following warning:

> Attribute *ngSwitchCase is not allowed here

[image: Manual correction warning]

Is there a way to make IntelliJ accept that syntax? I already installed AngularJS plugin, but it doesn't seem to be enough. Plus, it used to work with IntelliJ 2016.3.

Comment: The problem is similar with every directive: ngIf, nfSwitchDefault, ngFor, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue; [WEB-26200](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26200) is fixed in 2017.1.1 that is coming soon

Comment: Any update on this ?  This is still an issue for me... I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ